# Moving multiple points using QGIS

Tags: qgis, vertices

I worked with a photo that is apparently a bit offset.

Now I have more then 10,000 points with that offset.

Now that I have the correct map I would like to move them all to their new location.

Is there a way to move them all at once?

I did not manage to do that with the vertex tool on QGIS 3.14 Pi.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

If you know the exact offset, you can use "Affine Transform" or "Translate" from processing toolbox:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can use `Move Feature` tool that is located at the `advanced Digitizing Toolbar`. You need to select the points that you want to offset, and then use the `Move Feature` tool to move all the selected points at once. The following illustration will show you how to do that:

[image]